# Refresh all images with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, refresh, partial-page-refresh

I am trying to load the latest image from a CCTV server for each of our cameras on our network.

I have the following code, which works correctly and refreshes the image constantly. However, on the final version of the page there will be around 10 camera images on the page. I was wondering if the code I have now could be altered to refresh all images - not just specific ones.

At first I thought I could just use the same identifier for each image, but then I realised that the source of each image differs.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>CCTV Test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    newImage = new Image();

    function LoadNewImage()
    {
        var unique = new Date();
        document.images.ward.src = newImage.src;
        newImage.src = "http://192.168.1.64/image/WARD?time=" + unique.getTime();
    }

    function InitialImage()
    {
        var unique = new Date();
        newImage.onload = LoadNewImage;
        newImage.src = "http://192.168.1.64/image/WARD?time=" + unique.getTime();
        document.images.ward.onload="";
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://192.168.1.64/image/WARD" name="ward" onload="InitialImage()">
</body>
</html>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Loop through the `document.images` list, and refresh the image.

Comment: I'm completely new to JS, an links to tutorials etc. that could explain a bit more on how to loop through things, as per your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: '$("img").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prop("src"));
});'?

Comment: How do you determine the source of each image? Is it fixed, i.e., you have, say, 10 different sources for each image?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed. They each have their own URL. The URLs will never change (well, not within a few years).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CCTV Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="http://192.168.1.64/image/WARD?time=...">
  <img src="http://192.168.1.64/image/WARD?time=...">
  etc.
  <script>
  setInterval(function() {
      var images = document.images;
      for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
          images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(/\btime=[^&]*/, 'time=' + new Date().getTime());
      }
  }, 10000); // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will refresh all images every 10 seconds.

A different approach is to store the locations of the images in an array.

Comment: Do make sure your images are served with a `Cache-control: no-cache` header, BTW, or you'll end up stuffing your browser cache full of 1000's of CCTV frames.  You didn't say what server you were using, but on Apache, you can do this in the server config, or else using a .htaccess file.